# Dealing with file io in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a program that takes input for names and outputs the last names in a string. The task I have now is to include FileIO in it. Specifically, "get user input for the filename, and then read the names from the file and form the last name string."

When I run the program, the console will show the name string from the text file. But only initially. As you keep entering names, that string disappears. Also, my user input for file name seems to be doing nothing, because I can enter anything and it still show the string of last names from the text file.

[image: Output of program]

Here is what I have so far. Included all of it, just to make sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// function declerations 
int Menu();
void getName(vector<string> &names, int &count);
void displayName(vector<string> &names, int count);
string getLastNames(vector<string> &names, int count);

int main()
{ 
    vector<string> names;
    int count = 0;
    int choice = Menu();
    ifstream File;
    string line;

    
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    getline(cin,line);
    
    File.open("File.txt");
     
    while(File.good()){ 
        getline(File,line); 
        
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    
    File.close(); 


    
    while (choice != 0)
    {     
         // switch statement to call functions based on users input
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1: {
                getName(names, count);
            } break;
            
            case 2: { displayName(names, count); } break;
    
            case 3: { 
                cout << getLastNames(names, count) << endl; 
            } break;
            case 0: {
                return 0; 
            } break; 
        }
        choice = Menu(); 
    }
    return 0; 
}

// function definition for vector of strings
void getName(vector<string> &names, int &count)
{ 
    string name;
    
    // get input for name
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    
    // find position of space in string
    int pos = name.find(' ');
    
    // reverse order of name
    if(pos != -1) {
        string first = name.substr(0, pos);
        string last = name.substr(pos+1);
        name = last + "," + first;
    }
    
    // add name to end of vector
    names.push_back(name);
    count++; 
}
// give user option of what to do 
int Menu() {
    int choice;
    cout << "1. Add a name" << endl;
    cout << "2. Display names " << endl;
    cout << "3. Show all Last Names" << endl;
    cout << "0. Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a option: ";
    cin >> choice;
    
    // if outside of above choices, print 'choice not on list'
    while (choice < 0 || choice > 3)
    { 
        cout << "Choice not on list: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    return choice; 
}

// defining function that gets last names
string getLastNames(vector<string> &names, int count) {
    stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        int pos = names[i].find(',');
        if (pos != -1) {
            ss << "\"" << names[i].substr(0, pos) << "\", ";
        } else {
            ss << "\"" << names[i] << "\", ";
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}

// display the names
void displayName(vector<string> &names, int count)
{ 
    if (count == 0)
    {
        cout << "No names to display" << endl;
        return; 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    { 
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: you get a file name from the  user, then open the file with a different name. you then read lines from the file, display them and discard them. how could any of this work?

Comment: @NeilButterworth So I fixed the first part, by making sure they are the same file. But how would I go about stopping the lines from discarding? Thanks for the help!

Comment: call getname on them as they are read?